# Flask-SQLAlchemy-Marshmallow Nesting

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I'm trying to serialize data from a One-To-Many relationship models using Marshmallow in Flask. I read the Marshmallow and SQLAlchemy docs, but couldn't make it work. Could anyone help me.

Models:

```
class Category(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'category_mn'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(45))
    status = db.Column(db.Integer, server_default=db.FetchedValue())
    items = db.relationship('Items', backref='category', lazy='dynamic')
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.FetchedValue())


class Items(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'items_mn'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category_mn.id'))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.FetchedValue())
```

Schemas:

```
class CatSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'status')


class ItemSchema(ma.ModelSchema):

    class Meta:
        model = Items
        fields = ('id', 'name')
    category = ma.Nested(CatSchema, many=True)
```

I'm looking for an output like this:

```
[{'id':1, 'name':'Test', 'category':{'id':1, 'name':'Test Cat'}}]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're referencing models that don't exist in your schemas.

Besides that, `category` in `Items` is not iterable (it's the "one" side of the "one-to-many" relationship), so the `many=True` parameter throws an error.

And `category` should appear in the `fields` attribute of the `Meta` class for `ItemSchema` so it actually appears in the serialization.

It should be like this:

```
class CatSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
  class Meta:
    model = Category
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'status')


class ItemSchema(ma.ModelSchema):

  class Meta:
    model = Items
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'category')
  category = ma.Nested(CatSchema)
```

Of course, you could simply not include the `fields` attribute in the meta classes at all, since `model` is already taking care of mapping the models.

Comment: would you please show what additional code is needed so the items appear in a serialized category object?